# How can I update from firebase-admin@5.12.0 to firebase-admin@6.0.0?

Tags: firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

1.
D:\Firebase>**npm install firebase-functions@latest firebase-admin@latest --save**

> firebase-functions@2.0.5 postinstall D:\Firebase\node_modules\firebase-functions
>
> node ./upgrade-warning

```
======== WARNING! ========

This upgrade of firebase-functions contains breaking changes if you are upgrading from a version below v1.0.0.

To see a complete list of these breaking changes, please go to:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff

npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\Firebase\package.json'

- mime-db@1.35.0 node_modules\compressible\node_modules\mime-db

- mime-db@1.35.0 node_modules\request\node_modules\mime-db

- mime-types@2.1.19 node_modules\request\node_modules\mime-types

D:\Firebase

+-- firebase-admin@6.0.0

| +-- @google-cloud/storage@1.7.0

| | +-- compressible@2.0.14

| | | `-- mime-db@1.35.0

| | `-- mime-types@2.1.19

| `-- @types/node@8.10.26

`-- firebase-functions@2.0.5

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\Firebase\package.json'

npm WARN Firebase No description

npm WARN Firebase No repository field.

npm WARN Firebase No README data

npm WARN Firebase No license field.
```

2. D:\Firebase\functions>**npm install --save firebase-functions@latest**

> firebase-functions@2.0.5 postinstall D:\Firebase\functions\node_modules\firebase-functions
>   node ./upgrade-warning

```
======== WARNING! ========

This upgrade of firebase-functions contains breaking changes if you are upgrading from a version below v1.0.0.

To see a complete list of these breaking changes, please go to:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff

functions@ D:\Firebase\functions

+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY firebase-admin@5.12.0

`-- firebase-functions@2.0.5

npm WARN firebase-functions@2.0.5 requires a peer of firebase-admin@~6.0.0 but none was installed.
```

~

3. I check "**package.json**"

   "dependencies": {
       "firebase-admin": "~5.12.0",
       "firebase-functions": "^2.0.5"
     },

**How can I update from firebase-admin@5.12.0 to firebase-admin@6.0.0 ?**

Thanks very much.

Comment: I think the tilde `~` in package.json before the version number is what is messing you up. It allows minor version number changes (middle number) only. see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22345808/1291935

Comment: my package.json is in "D:\Firebase\functions"

Answer (score 13):

To get the latest version of any npm module for your Cloud Functions project:

```
cd functions
npm install firebase-admin@latest
```

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I kept running `npm install` and `npm install firebase-admin@latest` (as suggested in the warning message itself) under **/[project]/functions** and getting the same warning.

I realized I had forgotten to run this update:

`npm install --save firebase-functions@latest`